# Identifying WiFi clients connected to ESP8266

Tags: wifi, esp8266

I'd like to know that a specific device (phone/tablet) has joined my WiFi network created by ESP8266 microcontroller. It shouldn't require any installed apps on that phone/tablet, if possible, to simplify the whole setup.

So I think I need to somehow identify connected clients, and MAC is not an option because it is subject to change randomly on, say, Apple devices.

Maybe it's possible to collect host names of connected clients?

I know that Windows and Ubuntu clients send their host names when getting IP from DHCP server (see [here](http://www.held.org.il/blog/2011/01/make-dhcp-auto-update-dynamic-dns/)). Also, it's possible to find such information on, say, home Wi-Fi router admin web page (i.e. host names, their IPs and MACs).

I'm running DHCP server on ESP8266, but I haven't found any API that allows to get peer host name (i.e. reverse DNS). Does ESP8266 support getting such information?

Comment: IMHO this is really up to DNS. You may as well try the DNS server for Arduino (just google Arduino DNSServer). I don't think the bottom SDK offers the functionality you want since it uses lwip which afaik does only have support for somewhat customized DNS model, but maybe I'm wrong and in that case the keywords you are looking for are lwip mdns.

Comment: Actually the MAC can be reliable if it is not spoofed -- you can deduce the manufacturer from it. Take e.g. this iPad MAC `4C:B1:99:0D:DD:4C` and plug it into https://macvendors.com/ , it will give you `Apple, Inc.`. Should also work for smartphone manufacturers like samsung, nokia etc..

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt but newer iPads and iPhones do spoof MAC for privacy concerns, don't they?

Comment: @Pyjong do the clients auto-register themselves in DNS server? I heard they do so through DHCP server, but I don't know if lwip supports that option.

Comment: Ah wait.. it is actually done by dhcp, my bad! Unfortunately, if you take the dhcp server from espressif (lwip/app/dhcpserver.c), the options field (that contains the hostname) of dhcp discovery message doesn't seem to be taken use of. Appart from that, the header doesn't seem to provide any api apart from dhcp_start and dhcp_stop. I think you would have to modify the mentioned file somewhere in the function handle_dhcp().

Comment: You can use the `esp-open-rtos` SDK which is the open-source spinoff of the Espressif SDK. It has an open-source implementation of the DHCP server. If the hostname is transmitted there, you can catch it there. (https://github.com/SuperHouse/esp-open-rtos/blob/master/extras/dhcpserver/dhcpserver.c)